# How do you display letter by letter writing in visual basic?

Tags: string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, file-io

If you've played games you might know what I mean. How the words are spelled out letter by letter instead of the whole text being displayed kinda like pokemon or some other game.

this is what I have so far:

```
Dim strTitle As String = " "
    If IO.File.Exists("npcCraig.txt") = False Then
        outfile = IO.File.CreateText("save.txt")
    End If

    infile = IO.File.OpenText("npcCraig.txt")
    Do Until infile.Peek = -1
        strTitle = infile.Read 'reads character or should at least
        lblTitle.Text = lblTitle.Text + strTitle
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
    infile.Close()
    outfile.Close()
```

It runs but form1 doesn't show up at all because of  "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)".
I tried using that as a way to delay it but that didn't work obviously.

If you can could you also tell me how to put a break in it or something so that when the user presses a key the text loads completely and the player can keep going. I'm at a lost with that.

ANY HELP AT ALL WOULD BE A AMAZING!! My textbook and the rest of the internet was of no help

Comment: Can you describe what you mean? Do you mean putting up a single letter for one second then replacing it with another letter? Or do you mean _scrolling_ the letters?

Comment: a timer would seem more appropriate than Thread.Sleep().

Comment: displays a character, slight delay, then displays next character until the whole text is shown.

Answer (score 0):

My best shot is this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim M As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim T As String = "" + TextBox1.Text
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Mid(T, M, 1)
        M = M + 1
    End Sub
    'You can use any trigger here
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```